# nuspec and csproj package version tags

Tags: .net, nuget, versioning, nuget-package

I have a new ASP/.NET Core project that I publish to NuGet. What's the recommended approach to keep the version tags in `x.csproj` and `x.nuspec`  in sync when I publish a new package?

Comment: You probably don't need .nuspec anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With new `.csproj` format, you can [add all of the information to generate NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties) in the `.csproj` file. There is no longer a reason to use a `.nuspec` file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyTitle>My NuGet Project</AssemblyTitle>
    <Description>Something I decided to release on NuGet.</Description>
    <PackageTags>my;project;whatever;</PackageTags>
    <Authors>Me (who else)</Authors>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/theprojectname</RepositoryUrl>
    <PackageLicenseUrl>https://github.com/theprojectname/blob/master/LICENSE.txt</PackageLicenseUrl>
    <PackageProjectUrl>http://myproject.org/</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageIconUrl>https://github.com/theprojectname/blob/master/branding/logo/icon-128x128.png?raw=true</PackageIconUrl>
    <Copyright>Copyright © 2006 - 2018 Me</Copyright>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

Some of the elements (such as `<PackageId>`) default to using settings from the rest of the project file, so you don't need to add them unless you need them to be different than the defaults.

Note you must use [`dotnet pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x) (rather than the old [`NuGet.exe` CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference)) or Visual Studio 2017 in order to utilize this feature.